# Contact Form 7 Button Editable Via Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using Contact Form 7 on a website I'm working on, it is being used as an inquiry form in the sidebar. Now the client would like this form to have the button text (e.g. Request a Quote) editable per page, I do not want to make a different sidebar for every page because that wouldn't be user friendly and there's over 100+ pages.

I was wondering there must be a way to do this with Advanced Custom Fields as I have managed it with the widget title. Any help/advice will be appreciated as I just need to find where the submit button and text is echo'd.

**Update:** You can execute PHP inside the "Edit form" area but not between speech marks. Hmm.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/

Comment: i'm not sure how to or if there is a way to do it with custom fields. However, I would ask your client what type of button text he has in mind. If he says he has five different things he knows he wants it to say. Just create 5 different forms, sidebars, or whatever.. and target them with 5 different classes. If all else fails, sometimes the answer is NO! The customer is not the professional, you are, tell him that!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting to do this in future here is the solution:

Go to the contact form 7 directory > modules > submit.php

Put your ACF field in a variable like so:

```
$test =  get_field('form_button');
```

And then change

```
$atts['value'] = $value;
```

to

```
$atts['value'] = $test;
```